# All tasks in Queue done, but program not continuing

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a thread class defined like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import subprocess

class PingThread (threading.Thread):
    ipstatus = ''
    def __init__(self, ip):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ipaddress = ip


    def ping(self, ip):
        print 'Pinging ' + ip + '...'
        ping_response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
        if '100.0% packet loss' not in str(ping_response):
            return True
        return False

    def set_ip_status(self, status):
        self.ipstatus = status

    def get_ip_status(self):
        return self.ipstatus

    def run(self):
        self.ipaddress = self.ipaddress.strip('\n\t')
        pingResponse = self.ping(self.ipaddress)
        if pingResponse:
            self.set_ip_status(self.ipaddress + ' is up!')
        else:
            self.set_ip_status(self.ipaddress + ' is down!')
```

I am going through a list of ip addresses and sending it to the `PingThread` and having this class ping the ip address. When these threads are all done I want it to go through and get the status of each one by calling `get_ip_status()`. I have `q.join()` in my code, which is supposed to wait until all items in the queue are complete (from my understanding, correct me if I'm wrong, still new to threading) but my code never gets passed the `q.join`. I tested and all threads do get completed and all ip addresses get pinged, but `q.join()` isn't recognizing that. Why is this? What am I doing wrong? I am creating the threads like this:

```
q = Queue.Queue()
for ip in trainips:
    thread = PingThread(ip)
    thread.start()
    q.put(thread)
q.join()
while not q.empty():
    print q.get().get_ip_status()
```

Comment: `but q.join() isn't recognizing that` - what exactly you mean by that?

Comment: @thefourtheye my program calls q.join() which `Blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.`...all my items get processed fine, but it doesn't unblock. It stays tuck at the q.join() linee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how `Queue.join` works. `Queue.join` is meant to be used with `Queue.task_done`; On the producer end, you `put` items into the `Queue` on one end, then call `Queue.join` to wait for all the items you've `put` to be processed. Then on the consumer end, you `get` an item from the `Queue`, process it, then call `Queue.task_done` when you're done. Once `task_done` has been called for all the items that have been `put` into the `Queue`, `Queue.join` will unblock.

But you're not doing that. You're just starting a bunch of threads, adding them to a`Queue`, and then calling `join` on it. You're not using `task_done` at all, and you're only calling `Queue.get` after `Queue.join`, and it looks like you're just using it to fetch the thread objects after they've completed. But that's not really how it works; The `Queue` has no idea there a `Thread` objects in it, and simply calling `Queue.join` won't wait for the `Thread` objects inside it to complete.

Really, it looks like all you need to do is put the threads in a list, then call `join` on each thread.

```
threads = []
for ip in trainips:
    thread = PingThread(ip)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
    print thread.get_ip_status()
```

Comment: He _is_ calling `get`; the problem is that he's not calling it until after the `join`, which will obviously block forever. And the other problem is that he's not calling `task_done` when he calls `get`. And the other other problem is that he doesn't really need a queue for this at all…

Comment: @abarnert Yes, that's true, though it seems like he expects `join` to unblock when the threads have exited, just because they're inside the `Queue`. It doesn't seem like he realizes that the behavior of `join` is tied to calling `get`/`task_done` at all. I've updated my answer to more accurately reflect what his code does.

Comment: Yeah, I think he's expecting threads to act like futures, and a queue of threads to act like a composed futures collection roughly equivalent to `concurrent.futures.as_completed` or something…

Answer (score 2):

As the docs say, [`Queue.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.join)

> Blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.

But you don't every try to get the items until *after* the `join` (and even then, you don't mark them processed).

So, you can't get past the `join` until you finish the `while` loop, which you can't get to until you get past the `join`, so you block forever.

To make that `join` work, you'd have to change those last three lines to something like:

```
while not q.empty():
    print q.get().get_ip_status()
    q.task_done()
q.join()
```

However, a much simpler solution is to just not `join` the queue. Instead, you *could* `join` all of the threads; then you know it's safe to `get` all the values. But note that if you do this, there's no reason for the queue to be a `Queue`; it can just be a plain old `list`. At which point you've effectively got [dano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29703273/908494).

Alternatively, you could change your code to actually make use of the queue. Instead of putting the threads in the queue, pass the queue to the thread function, and have it put its results on the queue, instead of storing it as an attribute. Then, you can just loop over the `get()` as you're doing, and it will automatically take care of all the blocking you need. The example for [`Queue.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.join) in the docs shows how to do almost exactly what you'd want to do.

The advantage of the latter solution is that you no longer need your tasks and threads to map one-to-one—e.g., use a pool of 16 threads running 128 tasks, and you're still going to end up with 128 values on the queue.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* But if you want to do that, you probably may to use `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` or (from the `concurrent.futures` backport on PyPI) `futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of building it yourself.</sub>

Comment: Checking queue.Empty does not guarantee that all tasks are completed. In my program when I hit CRTL-C between queue.get() and queue.task_done(), queue.join() does not continue. I resolved it by first checking if queue is empty, and if it is, using (may not work if hitting CRTL-C when there is a pool of tasks not completed):       try:
        self.task_queue.task_done()
      except ValueError:
        pass